# Shader Node: How to loop a value input

Tags: node-editor, loop, looping

I have created a graphic item in Shader using nodes, I would like to automate this graphic by looping a section, I have tried using keyframes to link a Value_Input_Node to a music track, but it will not let me bake it to the f-curves.  It marks the value in the Value_Node like it recognises it as a valid entity, but that is all!

I am a noob at Blender, so if I am missing something really obvious forgive me.

I notice there are no loop_nodes, no recursive_nodes etc and I have tried creating a loop by feeding a result back into the first node in a Math Add loop to increment the value, no luck there either.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I have seen on Github there are addons that include a loop function for a loop node, but it looks so convoluted I would need to gain more experience before I could even consider attempting this as I do not even understand some of the terminology, lol!

Comment: You can input `#frame` into the value node, making the value equal to the frame number at any given moment. You could use a math node to play with this value and try to get the result you want based on the frame number.

Comment: OK thank you for your promt answer, I will be giving that a try.  It sounds like the sort of thing needed to increment the value.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Just to give you and others some feedback, #Frame caused a warning box to open to ask my permission to run the script, I gave it that permission, and it enabled me to link the Keyframe (using #Frame as the input in the Value Node) to the music, but I had to set the tick box (on the Burn Sound to F-Curves file view window) to 'Add'  this worked very well for my incremental graphics.  Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, glad it worked!

Comment: Just a question, what exactly did you put in the Value field, was it `#frame`, or `#Frame`. For me `#Frame` (as well as any other non int/float input) gives a warning, but `#frame` does not.